# Cannot create a Quote PDF with Apex when called from a Flow

Tags: salesforce, apex

I've created an `InvocableMethod` which is called from my Flow. This method simply creates a quote PDF and attaches it to the quote. This method looks like this:

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Create Quote PDF' description='Creates a PDF and saves it to the quote.')
public static void createPdf(List<string> quoteIds)
    {
        string quoteId = quoteIds[0];

        //Create pdf content
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id=xxx&summlid=yyy'); 

        //Document object of quote which hold the quote pdf
        QuoteDocument quotedoc = new QuoteDocument(); 

        //Get the content of Pdf.
        Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF() ;

        //content assign to document
        quotedoc.Document = b;

        //assign quote id where pdf should attach
        quotedoc.QuoteId = 'xxx';

        insert quotedoc; 
    }
```

This does not work when I execute my Flow; it will create a PDF and attach it to the quote but it will be blank. Funny thing is though, if I grab this code and execute in the anonymous window, it works fine! The PDF is generated as expected. It looks like it doesn't work if it's called from the Flow for some reason.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Possible solution (via SFSE) is to break the document generation out into a separate transaction via asynchronous Apex: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/221742/programmatically-generate-quote-pdf-in-lightning-component-apex-controller

Comment: @DavidReed my issue with a `future` method is that it won't be created instantly though. I'll give it a go nonetheless.

Comment: @DavidReed worked well, thanks for your help!